# reformat numerical values to two values

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a huge file with numerical values in many columns and rows. The values in the columns after column 6 are all numerical plus missing as `NA`  (`0` or `1` or `2` or `NA`).

I would like to change values in all columns from column 7 and on in this way:  `0` to `A A`, `1` to `A B`, `2` to `B B`, and `NA` to `0 0`.  In this way, the header from column 7, will be two times for each. Can I do this using `awk`? My input file is like this, but many columns after this. My output file should be tab-delimited.

```
id1 id2 parental    maternal    sex phenotype   A_101   A_102   A_103   
20907153    20907153    0   0   -9  -9  1   0   0   0   0   0   
31405729    31405729    0   0   -9  -9  0   0   0   0   0   0   
31450731    31450731    0   0   -9  -9  0   0   0   2   0   0   
41940308    41940308    0   0   -9  -9  0   0   0   NA  0   0   
52428081    52428081    0   0   -9  -9  0   0   0   0   0   0   
41943104    41943104    0   0   -9  -9  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: When you rewrite `0` to `A A`, are the two letters to be separated by a space or a tab?

Comment: You've asked and received multiple awk answers, presumably you're learning from them so - what have you tried?

Comment: yes, i mentioned tab limited above. thanks

Comment: Is that "yes" in response to my question? If so it doesn't answer what I've asked. It's quite possible to have tab-separated fields that contain spaces

Comment: i see, so the separation between A and A  should be tab limited to match with two times header. space is also fine as long as it match with header

Comment: So which is it, `A tab A` or `A space A`? It's your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of long, but straightforard:

```
awk '{ for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i=="0"){ sub(0,"A A",$i) } else if ($i=="1"){ sub(1,"A B",$i) } else if ($i=="2") {sub(2,"B B",$i) } else if ($i=="NA") { sub("NA","0 0",$i) }} print $0}' inputfile.txt
```

Loops over each field if field number >= 7, if matches one of your conditions, substitutes the field for corresponding pair. Prints full line after looping.

For me this returns:

```
id1 id2 parental    maternal    sex phenotype   A_101   A_102   A_103
20907153 20907153 0 0 -9 -9 A B A A A A A A A A A A
31405729 31405729 0 0 -9 -9 A A A A A A A A A A A A
31450731 31450731 0 0 -9 -9 A A A A A A B B A A A A
41940308 41940308 0 0 -9 -9 A A A A A A 0 0 A A A A
52428081 52428081 0 0 -9 -9 A A A A A A A A A A A A
41943104 41943104 0 0 -9 -9 A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

Comment: Don't do a string comparison and a regexp comparison+replacement like `if ($i=="0"){ sub(0,"A A",$i) }`, just do EITHER a string comparison+replacement `if ($i=="0"){ $i="A A" }` or a regexp comparison+replacement `{ sub(/^0$/,"A A",$i) }`, not both.